# NServicebus Publisher in WCF

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I want to Publish messages from WCF i have it configured as:

```
Bus =  Configure.With(typeof(Messages).Assembly)
.CustomConfigurationSource(new UserConfigurationSource(action))
.DefaultBuilder()
.MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
.BsonSerializer()
.MsmqTransport()
.IsTransactional(true)
.PurgeOnStartup(false)
.UnicastBus()
.ImpersonateSender(false)
.LoadMessageHandlers()
.CreateBus()
.Start();
```

but by some reason when the subscriber runs, it does not register as Subscriber, so never receives anything, here is the config of the client:

```
IBus Bus = Configure.With()
.CustomConfigurationSource(new UserConfigurationSource(unicast, msqm))
.StructureMapBuilder(container)
.MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
.BsonSerializer()
.MsmqTransport()
.IsTransactional(true)
.PurgeOnStartup(false)
.UnicastBus()
.ImpersonateSender(false)
.LoadMessageHandlers()
.CreateBus()
.Start();
```

Is there something im Missing?

[EDIT]
I have also tried with the WithWeb in the Service with no luck.

[EDIT]
Also saw this [message](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/9150)

is that really the only option? create another process?

[EDIT]
seems like is the only option so i will go with [that](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/).

Comment: Rene, what are you trying to accomplish by publishing from WCF?

Comment: We have a WCF Service that currently handles all requests done by some Windows Forms App, in that WCF Service we are calling at sometimes an external web service for our ERP, so i want to change that to a process Queue, so we can have retries and handle better when the ERP is down. So thats why i want to publish from my WCF Service.

Comment: Just so I understand, you have a WCF service (call it Svc1) that calls an external service (call it Svc2). You want to turn the calls to Svc2 to an NServiceBus queue. Then, you want to Svc1 to send messages to Svc2. If this is correct, then Svc1 should "Send" messages to Svc2, not "Publish".

Comment: We are trying to publish now to more than one now, so thats why i wanted publish, but how i done it now is i do Send to SVC2 and that one publishes.

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I have the same problem, I understand that creating another process is the better solution, but from what I read, this should still work, except it's not